# VBA Excel Range method

Tags: excel, vba

I need to move a row of data to another worksheet when a user chooses a value in a listbox.  I am trying to use the following code to select the row on the new worksheet I want to move the data to:

```
'Move data to the "Red" worksheet
Sheets("Red").Range ("A11").Select
```

I am getting an "Object does not support this property or method" error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the macro recorder and manually perform the operation you want.  Then you can look at the code recorded by Excel and clean it up to suit your needs.

The macro recorder is the easiest way to figure out whatever convoluted syntax VBA wants you to use.

Comment: question was, what am i doing wrong, not how can i use the macro recorder, no?

Answer (score 4):

There should NOT be a space between "Range" and "(".

Answer (score 1):

1. Is selecting allowed on your sheet? (= selection not prohibited by protection)
2. I have noticed a space character between the word Range and ("A11"). This might have caused a syntax error.

Comment: actually this is the best answer. troubleshooting plus syntax correction.